# How to set up an admin user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple relationship

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :schools
end
```

A user can be part of many schools but at the same time a user might be the admin of a number of schools. I set up a many-to-many relationship to represent this however I'm not sure how I would distinguish between admins and simple users.

I initially thought of setting a table which has a school_id and a user_id and every entry will represent the school id and the user id of any admins that the school has however I'm not sure how I would represent this in rails or if it's the best way to solve this problem? And if it is, how do I access the table without a model associated to it?

What I mean by what I said above:

```
school_id user_id
    1       3
    1       4
```

Which means that the school with id 1 has 2 admins (3 and 4)

Comment: Have you already made the required join table for this `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship or is that your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a more complex many_to_many relationship between school and user called [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). This relationship allows you to have many to many relationship with access to the table that represents the relationship. If you use that relationship, your models should look something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :school_roles
  has_many :schools, through: :school_roles
end

class SchoolRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  belongs_to :user
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :school_roles
  has_many :users, through: :school_roles
end
```

And the migrations of those tables would look something like this:

```
class CreateSchoolRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :schools do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :school_roles do |t|
      t.belongs_to :school, index: true
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.string :role
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I would suggest to make the "role" field in the "school_roles" migration an integer and then use an [enum](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#active-record-enums) in the model like so:

```
class SchoolRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  belongs_to :user

  enum role: [ :admin, :user ]
end
```

which allows you to add more roles in the future, but it's your call

Answer (score 0):

combining polymorphic association with `has_many :through` in my opinion is best option.

Let's say you create supporting model `SchoolRole`, which

```
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :school
 belongs_to :rolable, polymorphic:true
```

This way:

```
    class School ...

    has_many :administrators, :as => :schoolroles
    has_many :users, :through => :administators



@school.administrators= [..., ...]
```

It is quite agile.

```
@user=@school.administrators.build()



  class User
    has_many :roles, :as => :rolable
    def admin?
    admin=false
    self.roles.each do |r|
    if r.role_type == "administator"
    admin=true 
    break
    end
    end
   admin
    end
....
```